# Automate OneDrive Authentication with AAD MFA with python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm finding a way to automate the authentication from AAD with python.
In the past i used username and password for login to OneDrive and it worked properly. Here is the code:

```
pca = msal.PublicClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY_URL)
token = pca.acquire_token_by_username_password(USERNAME, PASSWORD, SCOPES)
```

Now, that i have two factor authentication i cannot use the same code to access OneDrive account.
I've searched the internet but all the solutions that i found requires to open the browser, and i can't do this because python script is a chronjob and runs in the late night. I need a solution that works in "background" without any action required.

Possibly it's better if there is a solution with MSAL library due to some permissions that i should request if i would change the library.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the Client-Credentials Grant flow or OAuth2. You would have to modify your cronjob to move away from fetching a token on behalf of the user and update it to acquire a token as the application using the application's identity (the app registration done in AAD). Upgrading to client-credentials flow, which is actually designed for scenarios similar to yours, will help you in situations where you cannot afford user interaction and you want the service to work in the backend.

For more information on Client-Credentials flow, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).
Also, you can refer to the following python app that implements client-credentials flow:

- [Call Microsoft Graph API using App Client Secret](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/tree/master/1-Call-MsGraph-WithSecret)
- [Call Microsoft Graph API using App Client Certificate:](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/tree/master/2-Call-MsGraph-WithCertificate)